# Run batch over results of ls command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, shell-script

I have a folder which got several folders.
I get list of all folders using below command:

```
ls -1a -d */
```

It returns something like this:

```
folder01/
folder02/
folder03/
...
```

Usually I store result of this script to a text file and then create a second shell script file which process folders which returned by ls command  and store it in `.sh` file to run them as a batch. So shell file will be something like this:

```
./process_folder.sh sample/folder01/
./process_folder.sh sample/folder02/    
./process_folder.sh sample/folder03/
./process_folder.sh sample/folder04/
```

As you can see I run `./process_folder.sh` over results of ls command and alos there is a small change an it is I've added `sample/` before name of each folder.

So the questions is how can I do all this using a command in my shell? (As i remeber I could use `|` or `>` but I couldn't remember the details).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't programmatically parse the output of `ls`.**

The output of `ls` is designed for human consumption, not programmatic. There are multiple ways in which parsing it directly can break, more or less subtly. Just as an example, if I run the command you gave, I get different output:

```
$ mkdir -p newdir/folder0{1,2,3}
$ cd newdir
$ ls -1ad */
folder01//
folder02//
folder03//
$
```

See those double slashes? That's because I have aliased `ls` to `ls --color=auto -F`.

It's better to use a tool that is designed for or can at least be well pressed into service for the job. **I suggest turning to `find`.**

```
$ mkdir -p newdir/folder0{1,2,3}
$ cd newdir
$ find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf './process_folder.sh sample/"%P"/\n'
./process_folder.sh sample/"folder03"/
./process_folder.sh sample/"folder01"/
./process_folder.sh sample/"folder02"/
$
```

`-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` limits the search to only the given starting directories (only `.` in this case) and excludes the starting directory itself. `-type d` limits matches to only directories. `-printf` is an action that find can take, which prints metadata about the directory entry found with a given format; `%P` in the format string is substituted by the name of the entry found minus the starting directory. See `man 1 find` for more details.

If you want to create a script to run later, redirect the output of `find` to a file:

```
$ find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf './process_folder.sh sample/"%P"/\n' > process_folders.sh
```

If you want a single command that executes the commands immediately, instead pipe the output of `find` into a shell:

```
$ find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf './process_folder.sh sample/"%P"/\n' | bash
```

This is far less likely to break, and gives you what you want without turning to fancy rewriting of a command's output. As-is, I suspect that the only thing that can break this is if the directory names have double quotes in them.

Comment: I got three right answers, but this one is the most comprehensive one! Anyway I should thank Marius and Eugen

Comment: Besides, `-mindepth 1` was a required trick.

Comment: @VSB Yes, without `-mindepth 1` (or with the default `-mindepth 0` explicitly specified), `find` also prints the starting directory, which is obviously not what you want.

Comment: Oh, It seems this one will run, it will only print result which can be used as a shell script inside an `.sh` file.

Comment: @VSB I thought that was what you wanted based on your statement that *"I store result of this script to a text file and then create a second shell script file which process folders"*, but I just edited the answer with how to run it immediately as well.

Comment: @VSB There. This answer as it stands now gives you all three options: just print the commands; write the commands to a file to be executed later; and execute the commands immediately.

Comment: May I ask something more, please?  Running this method, result of find are unsorted, and since running this batch is time consuming so I have no idea how is the current progress. I had a look at answers like [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/34325/144963)  for sorting results but could not adapt it to my request. Can you help me about it?

Comment: @VSB Sure, you could replace `-printf './process_folder.sh sample/"%P"/\n'` with `-printf 'printf "%%s\\n" "%P"; ./process_folder.sh sample/"%P"/\n'` or something like that. Doing so will print the name of each directory as it is processed. (Yes, the double % and \ are intentional, and required.)

Comment: Thnaks but I mean are there any ways to pass find results with sorting o `process_folder.sh`? I mean first folder_01, then folder_02, ....<br/> currently process_folder.sh with print folder name but since result of find is shuffled it is hard to keep track of progress and in case of failure, I cannot somehow resume the process

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48032/discussion-between-michael-kjorling-and-vsb).

Answer (score 2):

You want a loop:

```
for d in $(ls -1a -d */); do
  ./process_folder.sh "sample/$d"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try the following command:

```
find . -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec bash -c ' /path/to/process_folder.sh "sample/${0##*/}" ' {} \;
```

This both finds the directories in questions, and runs *process_folder* on each one of them at the same time: a single command instead of two. Also, it is immune to parsing problems.